# Success and Failure notification for Redshift scheduled query

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-redshift, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I am able to successfully schedule a redshift query, which is not very fancy. Just simple truncate and load. I also created a SNS topic and attached to this query. I am getting an email notification when this query runs.
My question is - Is it possible to customize this email notification with custom body? For eg - In case of failure of this query, I should get an email which says "Redshift scheduled query failed" OR in case of successful completion, it should say "Redshift query was successfully completed".

Comment: Any update on this? I see you posted it 4 months ago, so maybe you figured it out yourself? I have the exact same question!

Comment: I'm dealing with the same issue. Seems you can setup a scheduled query to check the query history and setup a message based on that specific query. So if if finds records within the query history results that failed, it sends them across.

Comment: Any update on this? I am trying to implement the same thing, but it is not working for me as well.

Comment: I found a way to handle this via event bridge rule with pattern. Please have a look at my answer

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using the AWS Eventbridge Rule. Create a rule with the following pattern:

> {
> "source": [
> "aws.redshift-data"
> ],
> "detail-type": [
> "Redshift Data Statement Status Change"
> ],
> "detail": {
> "state": [
> "FAILED",
> "FINISHED"
> ]
> } }

This rule will be triggered whenever a scheduled query fails or completes successfully. You can set the target of this rule as an SNS topic which can forward the event payload to your email. Here is the sample payload you can expect in case a scheduled query fails:

> {"version":"0","id":"64207b01-e97e-b05a-c090-1ba0c3eee01f","detail-type":"Redshift
> Data Statement Status
> Change","source":"aws.redshift-data","account":"xxxxxx","time":"2023-04-13T11:04:38Z","region":"eu-central-1","resources":["arn:aws:redshift:eu-central-1:xxxxxx:cluster:xxxx-cluster"],"detail":{"principal":"arn:aws:sts::xxxx:assumed-role/RedshiftScheduler/xxxxx","statementName":"xxxxx","statementId":"65ecdd43-5c0e-4507-841d-5857c6835b1f","redshiftQueryId":1.6043919E7,"state":"FAILED","rows":-1.0,"expireAt":1.681642837E9}}

Hope it helps.

Comment: I slightly modified your answer to only get a notification if a scheduled query fails  
```  
{  
  "source": ["aws.redshift-data"],  
  "detail-type": ["Redshift Data Statement Status Change"],  
  "detail": {  
    "state": ["FAILED"]  
  }  
}  
```

Comment: Wouldn't this trigger an alert for any failed redshift query, not just scheduled queries?